# NSClassFromString returning nil - Swift 4 - iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I'm having an issue with `NSClassFromString` returning nil.

The code has been working solid in the past, but after some refactoring and updating to iOS 12 it's not working any more...

Code:

```
func recreateHistoryAction(pack: (id: String, date: Date, type: String, data: Data), done: @escaping (HistoryAction) -> ()) {
    if NSClassFromString(pack.type) as? HistoryAction.Type == nil {
        AnalyticsAssistant.shared.logError("pack.type \"\(pack.type)\" as class \"\(String(describing: NSClassFromString(pack.type)))\" does not conform to HistoryAction.Type.")
    }
--> let history_action_type = NSClassFromString(pack.type) as! HistoryAction.Type
    do {
        let tree = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: pack.data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
        let history_action: HistoryAction = history_action_type.init(tree: tree)
        // ...
    // ...
}
```

The log is printed, thereby the cast to `HistoryAction.Type` fails on the next line.

The log:

> pack.type "Pixel_Nodes.CreateNodeHistoryAction" as class "nil" does
>   not conform to HistoryAction.Type.

I've double checked the app namespace and class name, it's not the issue.

Subclass structure:

```
HistoryAction -> NodeHistoryAction -> CreateNodeHistoryAction
```

I've noticed something odd in the Debug Area; the `pack` tuple is represented twice; once as a local variable with good data and once as an argument with odd data (`pack.date` is 2001-01-01 and the `pack.type` is not showing anything).

Here's the Debug Area from a breakpoint at the arrow:

[image: Debug Area at Breakpoint]

@OOPer mention that this is just a error with the debugger tho.

Here's a popup of the `pack` after a crash:

[image: Popup on Crash]

Has anyone else encountered this?
Or am I missing something obvious?

Building on macOS Mojave, Xcode 10, Swift 4.
Running on an iPad with iOS 12, target iOS 10.

Comment: What's the point of using `NSClassFromString` and checking the type? Why not a normal `if let pack as? HistoryAction {` ? And what is `HistoryAction` and how is it related to your tuple?

Comment: Just confirm `pack.type` is indeed `"Pixel_Nodes.CreateNodeHistoryAction"`. Maybe `Pixel_Nodes` class name got changed during your refactor.

Comment: @rmaddy The check is just for debugging. `pack.type` is a string stored in Core Data, so my goal is to create a class type and initialize it, tho NSClassFromString is not working for me...

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yep `pack.type` is `"Pixel_Nodes.CreateNodeHistoryAction"`, and `Pixel_Nodes` is the namespace of my app (didn't change that), tho I have a sneaking suspicion the `NSClassFromString` method reads the other phantom argument I mentioned showed up in the Debug Area...

Comment: Forget about the debugger thing and concentrate on why you get nil form `NSClassFromString` with passing `Pixel_Nodes.CreateNodeHistoryAction`. It's just a bug of Debugger. Believe the output of your `logError()` and think what's happening based on the fact.

Comment: @OOPer ok, that's sounds reasonable, I'll try to run some tests with other `HistoryAction` class types!